# How to allow certain PHP functions when using sanitize_callback in the word press customizer

Tags: theme-development, theme-customizer, sanitization

Hi I am making my own theme in WordPress and setting up some customizer options and I have one for the text in my footer but I would like to still use `<? echo date('Y');?>`  in the footer to dynamically change the date so I don't have to keep going in and doing it manually but the sanitizer call-back obviously blocks it is there a way to still be able use that php function in the sanitizer
here is my code what I'm using

```
customizer.php

$wp_customize-> add_setting('set_copyright', array(
'type' => 'theme_mod',
'default' => "Copyright &copy; <?php echo date('Y'); ?> . All Rights Reserved",
'sanitize_callback' => 'esc_attr'
));

 $wp_customize-> add_control('ctrl_copyright', array(
'label' => 'Copyright Information',
'description' => 'Enter your copyright info',
'section' => 'sec_footer',
'settings' => 'set_copyright',
'type' => 'text',

));
```

/////

```
 footer.php

 <footer class="main-footer">
<div class="copy pt-3 pb-3">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col text-center ">
                <p class="small m-0"><?php echo do_shortcode( get_theme_mod( 'set_copyright', "Copyright &copy; <?php echo date('Y'); ?> . All Rights Reserved") ) ; ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This sort of theme mod is only capable of conveying a string into the markup regardless of any sanitization callback - any PHP included within the string will never be interpreted by the PHP engine, short of running the output through `eval()` which would be *extremely* dangerous and likely result in the theme failing review for any marketplace.

In this case, since you're running the mod value through shortcodes anyway, I think it would be easiest and provide the best end-user experience to just include a shortcode which outputs the current year, or as a wrapper around the `wp_date()` function:

```php
function wpse406257_date( $atts, $content ) {
  $atts = shortcode_atts( [
    'format'   => 'F j, Y',
    'timezone' => null,
  ], $atts, 'date' );

  $timestamp = !empty( $content ) ? strtotime( $content ) : null;

  return wp_date( $atts['format'], $timestamp, $atts['timezone'] );
}

add_shortcode( 'date', 'wpse406257_date' );
```

```php
//...
'default' => 'Copyright &copy; [date format="Y"] . All Rights Reserved'
//...
```

You could achieve a similar effect without shortcodes by running the string output through `str_replace()` and swapping out custom placeholders such as `{year}`.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I would like to keep the short codes in because they are used for other things like the phone number and address etc would that function be placed in the customizer.php where i have set up the setting and control or can it go in the functions.php file?

Comment: `functions.php` would be fine! `customizer.php` is a not a core component of a theme so I'm not really sure what effect placing it there might have - if that file's loaded as it is in the default themes, placing it there would have the same effect as placing it in `functions.php`... but given that the shortcode isn't really customizer-specific, I think `functions.php` is probably a better home for it.

Comment: I tried that code and it doesn't seem to be working for me i copied the function exactly  its still not showing the year in the footer.

Comment: Yikes I might have messed something up! I'll test my code as well when I have some time tonight.

Comment: @besty_01 You'll need to run `apply_shortcodes()` on the value when outputting for the shortcode to be printed.

Comment: i managed to sort the issue bosco i found a function online what does what converts the date to short code.        

        function wpb_date_today($atts, $content = null) {
        extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'format' => ''
         ), $atts ) ); 
 
        if ($atts['format'] == '') { 
       $date_time .= date(get_option('date_format')); 
       }  else { 
      $date_time .= date($atts['format']); 
      } 
      return $date_time;
     }   
     add_shortcode('date-today','wpb_date_today');

Comment: Hey @besty_01! I'm sorry for the super-late reply - any date shortcode would certainly work :) . I finally got around to testing my code and I made a mistake testing for `$content` - the condition should have been `!empty()` instead of `isset()`. But I'm glad you found a solution in any scenario